# Is there any way to have slanted box-shadows using only CSS?

Tags: css

I want something like the logo on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/), but with CSS instead of an image file so it can be resized. Is this possible?

Something like this image:

[image: CSS-Tricks Logo]

Comment: Simply No. Had there been any such way Chris Coyier (author of CSS Tricks) would be using it.

Comment: May be able to with a combination of `:before`/`:after` with `transform`/`box-shadow` set on it, but I'm not positive. I don't have time to come up with a working example at the moment, though :(

Comment: Won't even work with pseudo elements, the shadows will overlap and look ugly.

Comment: @Andrew, just have to add a wrapper ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pure CSS Slanted Shadow with Cut Corners

This took a little while to perfect, but it now has a slanted drop shadow under the banner which also has cut corners and multiple borders. All effects, including the background, logo, and shadow, are generated with pure CSS.

[View on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keKpP/61/)
[image: Pure CSS Slanted drop shadow with cut corners and multiple borders]

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div>
  <h1><span>CSS</span>-Tricks</h1>
  <h2>A Web Design Community</h2>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="body">
 <div></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    min-width:600px;
    background-image:-webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, #d8d2ce, #d8d2ce 6px, #ccc6c3 7px, #d8d2ce 8px);
    background-image:repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, #d8d2ce, #d8d2ce 6px, #ccc6c3 7px, #d8d2ce 8px);
    background-color:#d8d2ce;
}
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin:77px 46% 10% -10%;
}
.wrapper div:after,
.wrapper div:before {
    content:".";
    font-size:0;
    color:transparent;
    background-color:#bcb9b7;
    position:absolute;
    right:-12px;
    height:50%;
    width:40px;
    padding-top:2.5px;
    border-right:8px solid #afafaf;
}
.wrapper div:after {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, transparent 38px, #c5c5c5 38px, #c5c5c5 40px),
        linear-gradient(180deg, #c5c5c5 0px, #c5c5c5 2px, transparent 2px);
    border-top:8px solid #afafaf;
    top:-10px;
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(25deg);
    -ms-transform-origin:100% 0;
    -ms-transform: skewX(25deg);
    transform-origin:top right;
    transform: skewX(25deg);
}
.wrapper div:before {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, transparent 38px, #c5c5c5 38px, #c5c5c5 40px),
        linear-gradient(0deg, #c5c5c5, #c5c5c5 2px, transparent 2px);
    border-bottom:8px solid #afafaf;

    bottom:-10px;
    right:-12px;

    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-25deg);
    -ms-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -ms-transform: skewX(-25deg);
    transform-origin:bottom right;
    transform: skewX(-25deg);
}
.wrapper div {
    background:#bcb9b7;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    top:-8px;
    left:-8px;
    border:2px solid #c5c5c5;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 8px #afafaf;
    text-align:right;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:40px;
    letter-spacing:.05em;
    padding:.55em .7em .55em;
}
.wrapper div h1:after {
    content:"*";
    color:#e5e1de;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:relative;
    top:-.4em;
    font-size:.9em;
}
.wrapper div span {
    color:#444444;
}
.wrapper div h1 {

}
.wrapper div h2 {
    font-size:.26em;
    letter-spacing:.4em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#807B77;
    font-family:serif;
    margin-top:.2em;
}
.wrapper:before {
    content:".";
    font-size:0;
    color:transparent;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow:0 0 12px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-4px,10px) scale(.5, .5) matrix(1, .021, 0, 1, 10, 0) skewX(-25deg);
    -ms-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-4px,10px) scale(.5, .5) matrix(1, .021, 0, 1, 10, 0) skewX(-25deg);
    transform-origin:100% 100%;
    transform: translate(-4px,10px) scale(.5, .5) matrix(1, .021, 0, 1, 10, 0) skewX(-25deg);
    z-index:1;
}
.wrapper:after {
    content:".";
    font-size:0;
    color:transparent;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow:0 0 12px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-4px,-4px) scale(.5, .5) matrix(1, .021, 0, 1, 10, 0) skewX(25deg);
    -ms-transform-origin:100% 0;
    -ms-transform: translate(-4px,-4px) scale(.5, .5) matrix(1, .021, 0, 1, 10, 0) skewX(25deg);
    transform-origin:100% 0;
    transform: translate(-4px,-4px) scale(.5, .5) matrix(1, .021, 0, 1, 10, 0) skewX(25deg);
    z-index:1;
}


.body {
    border:8px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    position:absolute;
    top:165px;
    margin-left:13%;
    width:80%;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.body div {
    height:200px;
    background:white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: @JonathanSampson, lazy and busy. I'll get them in later today :) (or someone could be awesome and add them in for me?)

Comment: Here's a dabblet demo http://dabblet.com/gist/2597273 - works in all browsers that support the features used.

Comment: @Truth, I'm looking into improvements for it. I did quite a few hacks that shouldn't be necessary, just to get it finished quickly. I'll post again when it has been updated to my satisfaction.

Comment: @Truth, Jonathan-Sampson, I've adjusted my fiddle to match the provided site better.