# How to create a triangle in CSS3 using border-radius

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am using border-radius property to acheive rounded corners. But I am not sure how to get rounded corners of this shape. I tried giving same dimensions from either sides but they just dont give me the exact shape. Am I missing some CSS3 property here. 
  [image]

Just wondering if clip css property is the answer.

UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/YWnzc/136/

Comment: Um, that is a triangle. Where are the rounded corners?

Comment: How are you drawing this? is it an image?

Comment: do you have any code to show?

Comment: @Izzey This is an image but I have made this a div. I am using border-radius

Comment: This? http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Comment: @Mike border-radius only works for square divs as far as I know, you will have to edit the image some other way

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing rounded triangle with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913645/drawing-rounded-triangle-with-css)

Comment: I see the fiddle now, but the HTML in it produces a square. Are you trying to round the corners on a square or on a triangle?

Comment: @Mike, it's because no one quite understands exactly what you're trying to accomplish. But, as a side note, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454611/is-there-any-way-to-have-slanted-box-shadows-using-only-css/10455083#10455083) *might* be of help to you.

Comment: I can kind of round it using the link @ScottSimpson provided and border-radius: http://jsfiddle.net/EcCns/

Comment: @TimMedora: Thanks but I need to draw this triangle on top of a div that has say width and height of 400px and this triangle sits in the center of this div.

Comment: @ScottSimpson: The link is great but I need to draw this triangle on top of a div that has say width and height of 400px and this triangle sits in the center of this div.

Comment: @Mike Are you trying to achieve something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/YWnzc/154/)?

Comment: @Abody97: I need an edge like how I have in my pic.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Demo

```css
#player {
  margin: 32px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #222;
}

#inner {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: silver;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  left: -50px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#outer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 165px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="player">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should produce:

[image]

The effect is achieved by creating a square, rotating it with a CSS transform, rounding the corners, and clipping it with an outer box. The inner element can be adjusted as desired, so it is somewhat flexible.

http://css3shapes.com/ has some nice examples (note the heart at the bottom of the page)

### Alternatives

SVG images support shapes of this type and are supported in all modern browsers. Simple SVGs can be coded by hand as XML, and there are a variety of free/paid editors for working with them.

See also: [Raphaël, a library for working with vector graphics on the web](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/)

Comment: Thanks but I need to draw this triangle on top of a div that has say width and height of 400px and this triangle sits in the center of this div.

Comment: css3shapes has my answer. but I dont think I can superimpose any of those shapes on top of a div

Comment: You can absolutely position the shape you want on top of another `div`.

Comment: Woah... no need to use SVG for a triangle. You can use the `border` property alone, which when used properly to create a triangle, should work in IE7+ and pretty much all of Firefox, Chrome and Safari

Comment: @TimMedora: I want the edge and not the curve . Actually it should be  atriangle

Comment: It's not clear what you mean...I added a screenshot. You asked for rounded corners on a triangle, right?

Comment: @MusikAnimal - SVG is a viable option for a variety of things...and I would would like to see an example of a rounded triangle (as was requested) that works in IE7 using only CSS without using IE-specific transforms.

Comment: @TimMedora: sorry about that but it is actually a traingle. I called it rounded corners coz I was using border radius, may be 0 rounded corners :) also edited the title.

Comment: Radius is a straight line or distance from the center to the edge of a curve...if there's no curve, then there's no radius. If you just want a triangle, I think you have a bunch of options. See: http://jsfiddle.net/K44mE/9/

Comment: @TimMedora: that makes sense. Thanks  a Million for your time and effort.

Comment: @TimMedora Thanks tim for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Triangles in different sizes with border radius**

To flip or to change vertical alignment fork translateY() and rotate()

```css
/*triangle background large*/
.triangle-bg-lg, .triangle-bg-lg:before, .triangle-bg-lg:after { width: 25em; height: 25em; }

/*triangle background medium*/
.triangle-bg-md, .triangle-bg-md:before, .triangle-bg-md:after { width: 20em; height: 20em; }

/*triangle background small*/
.triangle-bg-sm, .triangle-bg-sm:before, .triangle-bg-sm:after { width: 15em; height: 15em; }

/*triangle background extra small*/
.triangle-bg-xs, .triangle-bg-xs:before, .triangle-bg-xs:after { width: 10em; height: 10em; }

/*triangle background extra extra small*/
.triangle-bg-xxs, .triangle-bg-xxs:before, .triangle-bg-xxs:after { width: 5em; height: 5em; }

/*common triangle style*/
.triangle-bg-lg,.triangle-bg-md, .triangle-bg-sm,.triangle-bg-xs,.triangle-bg-xxs {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin:2em auto;
    border-radius: 20%;
    transform: translateY(50%) rotate(30deg) skewY(30deg) scaleX(.866);
} 
.triangle-bg-lg:before, .triangle-bg-lg:after,.triangle-bg-md:before, .triangle-bg-md:after, .triangle-bg-sm:before, .triangle-bg-sm:after,.triangle-bg-xxs:before, .triangle-bg-xxs:after{
    position: absolute;
    background: #ccc;
    pointer-events: auto;
    content: '';
}
.triangle-bg-xs:before, .triangle-bg-xs:after{
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: auto;
    content: '';
}
.triangle-bg-lg:before, .triangle-bg-md:before, .triangle-bg-sm:before, .triangle-bg-xs:before,.triangle-bg-xxs:before {
    border-radius: 20% 20% 20% 53%;
    transform: scaleX(1.155) skewY(-30deg) rotate(-30deg) translateY(-42.3%) 
            skewX(30deg) scaleY(.866) translateX(-24%);
}
.triangle-bg-lg:after, .triangle-bg-md:after,.triangle-bg-sm:after,.triangle-bg-xs:after,.triangle-bg-xxs:after {
    border-radius: 20% 20% 53% 20%;
    transform: scaleX(1.155) skewY(-30deg) rotate(-30deg) translateY(-42.3%) 
            skewX(-30deg) scaleY(.866) translateX(24%);
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="triangle-bg-lg"></div>
    <div class="triangle-bg-md"></div>
    <div class="triangle-bg-sm"></div>
    <div class="triangle-bg-xs"></div>
    <div class="triangle-bg-xxs"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question properly. I think you can use something like below:

CSS:

```
#box{   border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FFFFFF;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 50px 0 50px 75px;
    height: 0;
    left: -40px;
    margin: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
 #outerbox{  background:red;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    width: 122px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="outerbox"><div id="box"></div></div>
```

LIVE DEMO

[http://jsfiddle.net/fsGQR//](http://jsfiddle.net/fsGQR/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.trio {position:absolute;}
.trio .triangle {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #DB524B;
    text-align: left;
}
.trio .triangle:before,
.trio .triangle:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: inherit;
}
.trio .triangle,
.trio .triangle:before,
.trio .triangle:after {
    width:  3em;
    height: 3em;
    border-top-right-radius: 33%;
}

.trio .triangle {
    transform: rotate(-60deg) skewX(-30deg) scale(1,.866);
}
.trio .triangle:before {
    transform: rotate(-135deg) skewX(-45deg) scale(1.414,.707) translate(0,-50%);
}
.trio .triangle:after {
    transform: rotate(135deg) skewY(-45deg) scale(.707,1.414) translate(50%);
}
.trio .exclamation{
    color: #DB524B;
    position:absolute;
    font-size:50px;
    top:8px;
    left:15px;
    z-index:2;
}

.trio .triangle.tri-in {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: -2.9em;
    margin-left: 1px;
}
.trio .tri-in,
.trio .tri-in:before,
.trio .tri-in:after {
    width:  2.9em;
    height: 2.9em;
    border-top-right-radius: 33%;
}
/* styles below for demonstration purposes only */
body { padding: 30%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="trio">
<span class="exclamation">!</span>
<div class='triangle'></div>
<div class='triangle tri-in'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't post code only answers. Go ahead and add an explaination.

Answer (score -1):

This is even better

CSS

```
.c1 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:yellow;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    position: relative;
    top: -65px;
    left: 25px;
    z-index:-1;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,255,0,.6);
}
.c2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 10000;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,255,0,.6);
    border-right: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="c2">Hello</div>
<div class="c1"></div>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/YWnzc/237/

Comment: Thats a pentagon and not a Triangle.

Comment: That doesn't seems to be triangle

Answer (score -1):

I used this for add triagle to link:

```
.review-box_left-link:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    background: #2195DB;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, white 0%,white 50%,#2195DB 50%,#2195DB 50%,#2195DB 100%);
}
```