# Rounded arrows with CSS

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a triangle in CSS3 using border-radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041938/how-to-create-a-triangle-in-css3-using-border-radius)

Are they possible to make with CSS?

Normal arrow:

```
.some_element:after{      
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;        
  top: 0;
  left: 0;       
  border: 100px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #000;           
}
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/W3xwE/ )

Rounded arrow (I want only the bottom side rounded):

[image]

:(

Comment: Don't think css has endcap capability (but I haven't looked at css3 too closely yet, so probably wrong on this count), but the html5 canvas element does have endcaps.

Comment: it can be done but it need some hack or you can do it html5? with the canvas scripts

Comment: Different orientation, but this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12042194/453277

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it is possible! You `rotate` the box, give it a `border-radius` and use a `45deg` `linear-gradient` as a `background`.

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3737782)

**HTML**:

```
<div class='arrow'></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.arrow {
    width: 7em;
    height: 7em;
    border-radius: 0 0 2em 0;
    margin: 5em;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, black 50%, transparent 50%);

}
```

If you want the angle of the arrow to be different, then you can also `skew` it.

Take into account the fact that [CSS gradients are not supported by IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) (I am not saying "or older" this time because you mention CSS3 among your tags). The solution in that case would be to use a solid background and to somehow make sure the upper part won't show, either by covering it with a preceding element, or by clipping it (see [the answer Tim Medora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461441/rounded-arrows-with-css/12461632#12461632) provided).

Also, at this point there is still no support for the unprefixed syntax (although this will soon change :D ), so you will need to either manually add the prefixes `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, and `-o-`. (I did not add them in the demo because Dabblet uses -prefix-free which takes care of doing this.)

Comment: mozilla firefox not support plz add code for that

Comment: `background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 50%, transparent 50%);` *before* the unprefixed version.

Comment: thanks :P I wish I knew CSS like you do :(

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it by placing a rotated square inside a box to control clipping. Personally, I think @Ana's solution is much cleaner.

http://jsfiddle.net/K44mE/14/

```
<div id="outer"><div id="inner">&nbsp;</div></div>

#inner{
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color:silver;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    top: -70px;
    left: 20px;
    position:relative;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#outer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 140px;
    height: 70px;    
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    overflow: hidden;    
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
 .arrow {
        width: 7em;
        height: 7em;
        border-radius: 0 0 2em 0;
        margin: -2em 2.5em;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        background: linear-gradient(-45deg, black 50%, transparent 50%);

    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='arrow'></div>
```

Comment: Ain't that funny? Looks just like the demo I did. Serves me right, I should believe in supernatural phenomena.

Comment: I don't know how this happened I thought the demo page was one of my search result page  :P