# How to draw a CSS petagon with all borders radius?

Tags: html, css

i find a cool pentagon css code, i can make `border-radius : 10px;` but it's active only in the "bottom" of the pentagon, how to apply border-radius even for the top of the pentagon ?

check the [JSFFIDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/pitmit/1ryce4hr/)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: what result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DmitryMalinovsky hi, i want to have the border radius in every border

Comment: You wouldn't be able to achieve this using your current method because CSS `clip-path` cannot support **paths** as yet. It can only support basic shapes like polygon, circle ellipse etc. You would need to use SVG `clip-path` and the `a` (arc commands) to create a curve for each corner. You can find sample for one corner in my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248443/is-it-possible-to-create-an-angled-corner-in-css/30729446#30729446

Comment: Maybe it may help you. Few years ago i've had similar problem http://codepen.io/brenna/pen/hbDqL although the code here is much more complicated.

Comment: @DmitryMalinovsky any help is welcome thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below solution is messy, so you are probably better off using an image. Based on this: [How to create a triangle in CSS3 using border-radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041938/how-to-create-a-triangle-in-css3-using-border-radius)

```css
#inner{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    background-color:silver;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    top: 20px;
    left: -50px;
    position:relative;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#outer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 70px;
    height: 140px;    
    top:20px;
    left:50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
}

#lower {
    top:99px;
    left:15px;
 width: 124px;
 height: 75px;
 background: silver;
 position: relative;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer"><div id="inner">&nbsp;</div></div>
<div id="lower"></div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6e1jv3h/1/)

Answer (score -2):

```
.gon {
    border-radius : 10px;
}
```

Comment: @AlexG: You'll see it works only on the bottom and not *all sides*. In the question itself OP stated that it works on bottom but wants it to work for top also.

Comment: @Harry: I see, it's a browser specific problem, check it out in firefox. That is causing the confusion.

Comment: Still, it does work in Chrome. You just can see the top borders.

Comment: @AlexG: I don't know if there is an understanding problem but (a) in Firefox I see two divs, one is ellipse another is rectangle with rounded borders but no pentagon (b) in Chrome I see one cone like shape first and then a pentagon with rounded corners at bottom and none on top. Anyway, lets wait for OP to respond (I wasn't the one who downvoted).

Comment: always include an explanation in your answer, please read [answer]