# I want to turn one oval css shape into oval with arrow

Tags: html, css, border, shapes

I currently have the following code. Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/073tcos8)

```
content:counter(step) !important;
counter-increment:step !important;
width:90px !important;
height:40px !important; 
line-height:35px !important;
/*border:3px solid #ddd !important;*/
display:block !important;
text-align:center !important;
margin: 0 auto 10px auto !important;
background-color: gray !important; /*white orig */

border-top-left-radius: 100em;
border-bottom-left-radius: 100em;
border-top-right-radius: 100em;
border-bottom-right-radius: 100em;
/*border-right: 10px solid white;*/
```

And it is like this:

[image: My Shape]

And I want it to be like this:

[image: Their Shape]

How can I make a shape like that?

Comment: Pls add a jsfiddle..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/073tcos8/

Comment: You can use pictures, or this : https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ (more complicated and doesn't work on old browsers)

Comment: You can't do that with a single element. You'd be better of with a background image or SVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a CSS only solution using pseudo elements `:before` and `:after`.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/073tcos8/6/)

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: step;
}
.progressbar li {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 35px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
}
.progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step) !important;
  counter-increment: step !important;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 4px;
  color: #666666;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.progressbar li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="progressbar">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Very nice, I couldn't figure out how to line up the rotated square, forgot about transform!

Comment: This worked!! Thank you!!! But, Is there a way to add another shape right after the "after"?

Comment: @VouchMe : Add another element next to `li` and apply styles as necessary!

Answer (score 3):

While its possible to do this entirely with CSS its probably going to be hard to get it to look perfect in all browsers and you will need extra HTML markup. Have a look at this question: [How to create a triangle in CSS3 using border-radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041938/how-to-create-a-triangle-in-css3-using-border-radius)

What I would do is make a SVG background like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 88 40" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" x="0px" y="0px" width="88px" height="40px">
    <g>
        <path d="M 66 40 L 66 39.755 C 68.7256 40.4302 71.7275 39.7039 73.8578 37.5735 L 85.5735 25.8578 C 88.8088 22.6226 88.8088 17.3774 85.5735 14.1422 L 73.8578 2.4265 C 71.7275 0.2961 68.7256 -0.4303 66 0.245 L 66 0 L 20 0 C 8.9542 0 0 8.9542 0 20 C 0 31.0458 8.9542 40 20 40 L 66 40 Z" fill="#888888"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Use that background on your `li` and then style your `:before` to just be the number in a white circle.

https://jsfiddle.net/v8b9s0vb/1/

Answer (score 1):

Its absolutely possible with pure css I've almost done it with css [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6y3w1qqu/)just change the values to get your desired output.

```
transform: translateY(50%) rotate(120deg) skewY(28deg) scaleX(.866);
```